# Android: Sqlite on ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I need help in creating a listview that shows the elements of a database sql..
for first created a small xml layout with 3 fields TextView with id: `Text1,Text2 and Text3`
and one listview in my activity.
After I have grouped the columns in an interface

```
public interface TableRegistry extends BaseColumns{

     String TABLE_NAME = "Registry";

     String TYPE = "Type";
     String DATE = "Date";
     String STATUS = "Status";
     String NUMBER = "Number";
     String MESSAGE = "Message";
     String OTHER = "Other";

     String[] COLUMNS = new String[]
                { _ID, TYPE, DATE, STATUS, NUMBER, MESSAGE, OTHER };
            }
```

After I created the database class..

```
public class APdatabaseClass extends  SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "APdatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public APdatabaseClass(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String sql = "CREATE TABLE {0} ({1} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
                " {2} TEXT NOT NULL,{3} TEXT NOT NULL,{4} TEXT NOT NULL,{5} TEXT NOT NULL,{6} TEXT NOT NULL, {7} TEXT NOT NULL);";
            db.execSQL(MessageFormat.format(sql, TableRegistry.TABLE_NAME, TableRegistry._ID,
                TableRegistry.TYPE, TableRegistry.DATE, TableRegistry.STATUS, TableRegistry.NUMBER, TableRegistry.MESSAGE, TableRegistry.OTHER));

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableRegistry.TABLE_NAME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);       
    }
```

Now how do I connect my database to listview in my activity with SimpleCursorAdapter or something? I need to populate the 3 TextView fields with:

```
TableRegistry.TYPE, TableRegistry.DATE, TableRegistry.STATUS.
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are going to a bit of extra work.  Here's how I do it normally:

First create  method in your database helper to fetch the information you want:

```
public Cursor fetchListData() {
    return mDb.query(TableRegistry.TABLE_NAME, new String[] { TableRegistry._ID,
        TableRegistry.TYPE, TableRegistry.DATE, TableRegistry.STATUS }, null,null, 
        null, null, null);
}
```

Then in whatever class you want to create the list:

```
APdatabaseClass mDbHelper = new APdatabaseClass(getActivity());
mDbHelper.open();

Cursor c = fetchListData();
getActivity().startManagingCursor(c);

String[] from = new String[] { TableRegistry.TYPE, TableRegistry.DATE, TableRegistry.STATUS };
int[] to = new int[] {  R.id.Text1, R.id.Text2, R.id.Text3  };
SimpleCursorAdapter data = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.yourlistlayout, c, from, to);
setListAdapter(data);
```

Note that this assumes you are using a ListFragment or ListActivity.  If you aren't, it would be slightly different in how you set the adapter.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can now fire queries by using [raqQuery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method, you will get Cursor in result.

Now, you have to iterate through the cursor and fetch the data.

For example,

```
Cursor cur = db.raqQuery("Select * from myTable",null);
if (cur != null) {
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Name"))); // "Name" is the field name in table
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
}
```